# App Bundle keystore lost, how to reset in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, keystore

I uploaded app to Google Store and now when I want to publish new version I forgot/misplaced my password. So is there any chance to recover it or to reset it? I have done my app in Unity. And also did stupid thing, when setting the new password I run over my first user.keystore file. Any solutions to get the password out of this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get the password out of a keystore. Keystores are encrypted security files. If you could get the password from the file, then that would mean that hackers could steal your key and use it. The fact that the key is overwritten does not make the situation any easier.

I hope you didn't already make your app publicly available on the play store. The only solution I could think of is to create a new app in the play store and an new key in unity.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled the new app signing by google play, it is possible to resubmit an app if you lost the key, see [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en):

> **Lost or compromised upload key?**
>
> If you’ve lost your private upload
>   key, or it’s been compromised, you can create a new one, and then ask
>   your account owner to contact support to reset the key. When
>   contacting support, make sure your account owner attaches the
>   upload_certificate.pem file.
>
> After our support team registers the new upload key, you receive an email, and then you can update your keystores and register your key with API providers.
>
> Important: Resetting your upload key doesn’t affect the app signing
>   key that Google Play uses to re-sign APKs before delivering them to
>   users.If you’ve lost your private upload

Here is the [link for customer support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs?hl=en) by google.